# jQuery - check for all links in DOM that do not have a #hash

Tags: jquery

With jQuery how do I detect all links on my page that do not have a hash tag?  This is the code I have so far to help me set a target action for all anchor links on the page.  I simply want to exclude any link from the DOM that has a hash in the href.

```
var mallinks = $('a');
if(mallinks.length) {
     mallinks.on({
        mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("target");
    }
    });
    mallinks.on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: For the love of god it's not a hashtag. Anyways, please post some HTML and preferably a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: where in the link are you looking for a #? in the `href`?

Comment: Yes in the href, it is simply **href="#"** if it has it

Comment: ``$("a:not([href*=#])")``

Comment: haha my bad @gibsonman507 - I've been away from the use of the proper terminology as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()`:

```
var mallinks = $('a').filter(function(){
    return this.href.indexOf('#') === -1;
});
```